# Xcode 9 Archive App for Development with App Thinning option

Tags: ios, ipa, xcode9

I am generating iPA for Development Distribution with `Xcode 9` and have this option in process.

[image]

kindly let me know which one is best for iPhones only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

App Thinning let you download iPA for different devices in different sizes to save space and optimise operating system.suppose i select `All compatible device variants`

[image]

i got multiple iPA of a App with different sizes along main iPA.

[image]

for further details.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH35-SW3

Comment: How it works in production... Do we get this option of Thinning when we create Production build manually ?

Comment: @AjaySharma this option is not available for production because Apple itself done this on Appstore.

Comment: I did it, but unfortunately iPhone 8 Plus and iPhone X versions were not built. What should I do?

Comment: What if have Enterprise app distribution?

Comment: @KirtiNikam: Have you figured this out, how to use these multiple files while enterprise distribution? If you have, please share the solution.